# Can you update all Mongo documents in a collection at once in Mule?

Tags: mongodb, mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to update the Effective date in my mongoDB collection with the current date.  I want to update all documents in the collection where the Effective Date is null.

How do you configure the transformer to do this?  The Query Reference field info message talks about an Id and the element field looks like it needs a payload containing a document that will replace the one being updated.  I am just looking to update one field and currently getting an error with my query but it does work on the mongoDB command line.

This is my query that I want to implement:

```
db.stores.update({"EffectiveEndDateTime" : null}, {$set : {"EffectiveEndDateTime" : "2017-01-13T18:56:55.257Z"}})
```

My XML configure for Mongo in Mule so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:mongo="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
    xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" 
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo/current/mule-mongo.xsd">
    <mongo:config name="Mongo_DB__Configuration" username="${mongodb.username}" password="${mongodb.password}" database="${mongodb.database}" host="${mongodb.host}" doc:name="Mongo DB: Configuration"/>
    <flow name="deactivateCurrentDocumentsFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="httpListenerConfig" path="/mongo" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <mongo:update-documents-by-function config-ref="Mongo_DB__Configuration" collection="stores" function="$set : {&quot;EffectiveEndDateTime&quot;: &quot;2017-01-13T17:51:08.153Z&quot; }" doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Error I am getting:

```
Message               : Failed to invoke updateDocumentsByFunction.
Payload               : {NullPayload}
Payload Type          : org.mule.transport.NullPayload
Element               : /deactivateCurrentDocumentsFlow/processors/0 @ test    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Unknown modifier: $set : {"EffectiveEndDateTime": "2017-01-13T17:51:08.153Z" }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use update documents by [Functions](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mongo-apidoc) variant.

```
<mongo:update-documents-by-functions config-ref="Mongo_DB"
  collection="myCollection" functions="$set,{"key":123}">
</mongo:update-documents-by-functions>
```

Comment: I've been unable to get the above to work.  I have added my code and have tried a number of variations but not luck so far.  Are you able to see where I'm going wrong?  I'm using the mongoDB 4.1 connector

Comment: Its `update-documents-by-functions` not `update-documents-by-function`. See if that helps and I'll look in the meanwhile. Same for the args. Change from `function` to `functions`

Comment: Managed to get it to work with this <mongo:update-documents-by-functions config-ref="Mongo_DB__Configuration" collection="#['stores']" functions-ref="#['{$set : {&quot;EffectiveEndDateTime&quot; : &quot;1234&quot;}}']" query-ref="#['{&quot;EffectiveEndDateTime&quot; : null}']" doc:name="Mongo DB"/>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I wouldn't have thought to look at functions.